# I don't know if my javascript file doesn't receive the json or my driver doesn't send them?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch-api

people who are up. I'm sending data when registering a user in the database. I'm trying to use the latest modern and the requests I'm sending not with ajax but fetch: Well the thing is that the user is inserted but it's not my php file that doesn't send the json or if it's the fetch it doesn't receive. That just because it won't let me play with javascript notifications or for example if I want to print the data that was entered I can't. Look at the code:

Javascript:

```
const datos=new FormData();
datos.append('nombre',nombre);
datos.append('email',email);
datos.append('usuario',usuario);
datos.append('contrasenia',contrasenia);
datos.append('rol',rol);

//Peticion api
fetch(`http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/save`,{
    method:'post',
    body:datos
})
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.respuesta);
    return res.json();
})
.then((data)=>{

})
.then(
    mostrarNotificacion('Usuario insertado','correcto'),
    this.reset()
)
.catch((error)=>{

})
```

Controller:

```
if ($errores=='success'){  
    $objUsuario=new Usuario();
    $objUsuario->setNombre($nombre);
    $objUsuario->setEmail($email);
    $objUsuario->setUsuario($usuario);
    $objUsuario->setPassword($password);
    $objUsuario->setRol($rol);

    $validar=$objUsuario->validateUsuario();               
    while($cantidad=$validar->fetch_assoc()):
        if($cantidad['conteo']=='1'){
            $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=>'error',
                'mensaje'=>'Este usuario ya existe'
            );
        }else{
            $save=$objUsuario->save();
            if ($save){
                $respuesta=array(
                    'respuesta'=>'exito',
                    'mensaje'=>'Usuario registrado correctamente'
                );
            }
        }
        endwhile;
}elseif($errores!="success"){
    $respuesta=array(
        'respuesta'=>'error',
        'mensaje'=>$errores
    );
}
}
die(json_encode($respuesta));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your javascript code, first you have to convert it to json with `res.json()` before getting the `res.respuesta`, try if this code works.

```
const datos=new FormData();
datos.append('nombre',nombre);
datos.append('email',email);
datos.append('usuario',usuario);
datos.append('contrasenia',contrasenia);
datos.append('rol',rol);

//Peticion api
fetch(`http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/save`,{
    method:'post',
    body:datos
})
.then((res)=>{
    return res.json();
})
.then((data)=>{
    var jsonRespuesta = data;
    console.log(jsonRespuesta.respuesta);
    mostrarNotificacion('Usuario insertado','correcto'),
    this.reset()
})
.catch((error)=>{

})
```

Apart from this, there is an additional `}` in front of `die(json_encode($respuesta));`. If so, you need to remove it.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: in the network i got {"respuesta":"exito","mensaje":"Usuario registrado correctamente"}

Comment: @Jesu `<` means the server responds with HTML instead of JSON. Simply hit `F12` for XHR debug.

Comment: @Jesu I gave you the right answer you have to use the data in the second then..